# Recycler view scrolling lag with custom adapter

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am making a meme generator wth around 150 entries.Each entry(meme class) has an image and a text view

The scrolling is slow with a lot of lag,yet an improvement over a normal listview.The app crashes after a certain point with the logcat showing this message-Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xf0 in tid 26637 (RenderThread)

Here is my code:

Meme class

```
    public class Meme {

    private String memeName;
    private int ImgResId;

    public Meme(String name, int imageResourceId)
    {
        memeName=name;
        ImgResId=imageResourceId;
    }
    public String getMemeName(){return memeName;}


    public int getImgResId(){ return  ImgResId;}
}
```

Meme Adapter

```
public class MemeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Meme> memeList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView meme_name;
        public ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            meme_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.meme_name);
            image=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.meme_icon);
        }
    }


    public MemeAdapter(List<Meme> memeList) {
        this.memeList = memeList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Meme meme = memeList.get(position);
        holder.meme_name.setText(meme.getMemeName());
        holder.image.setImageResource(meme.getImgResId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return memeList.size();
    }

}
```

the activity creating the list

```
    public class MemeListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MemeAdapter memeAdapter;
    private List<Meme> memeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_memelist);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        memeAdapter = new MemeAdapter(memeList);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(memeAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Meme meme = memeList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), meme.getMemeName() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MemeListActivity.this, EnterTextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("flag", 1);
                int id = meme.getImgResId();
                intent.putExtra("res-id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        prepareMemeData();
    }

    private void prepareMemeData() {
        // Create an ArrayList of Meme objects
        memeList.add(new Meme("aaaand it's gone", R.drawable.aaaaand_its_gone));
        memeList.add(new Meme("am i the only who", R.drawable.am_i_the));
        memeList.add(new Meme("angry indian father", R.drawable.amrish_puri));
        memeList.add(new Meme("all things", R.drawable.all_things));
        memeList.add(new Meme("ancient aliens", R.drawable.ancient_aliens));
        memeList.add(new Meme("angry baby", R.drawable.angry_baby));
        memeList.add(new Meme("angry doge", R.drawable.angry_doge));
        memeList.add(new Meme("arnab thug life", R.drawable.arnab_thug_life));
        memeList.add(new Meme("awkward seal", R.drawable.conf_seal));
        memeList.add(new Meme("condescending husky", R.drawable.angry_husky));
        memeList.add(new Meme("baby godfather", R.drawable.baby_godfather));
        memeList.add(new Meme("bad luck brian", R.drawable.bad_luck_brian));
        memeList.add(new Meme("batman slaps robin", R.drawable.batman_robin));
        memeList.add(new Meme("be like bill", R.drawable.be_like_bill));
        memeList.add(new Meme("bear grylls", R.drawable.bear_grylls));
        memeList.add(new Meme("brace yourselves", R.drawable.brace_yourselves));
        memeList.add(new Meme("buddy jesus", R.drawable.buddy_christ));
        memeList.add(new Meme("business cat", R.drawable.business_cat));
        memeList.add(new Meme("butthurt dweller", R.drawable.butthurt_dweller));
        memeList.add(new Meme("calm lemur", R.drawable.calm_lemur));
        memeList.add(new Meme("cereal guy", R.drawable.cereal_guy));
        memeList.add(new Meme("chemistry cat", R.drawable.chem_cat));
        memeList.add(new Meme("chuck norris", R.drawable.chuck_norris));
        memeList.add(new Meme("CID ", R.drawable.cid));
        memeList.add(new Meme("confused baby", R.drawable.conf_baby));
        memeList.add(new Meme("confession bear", R.drawable.confession_bear));
        memeList.add(new Meme("correction guy", R.drawable.correction_guy));
        memeList.add(new Meme("dekh bhai", R.drawable.dekh_bhai));
        memeList.add(new Meme("disaster girl", R.drawable.disaster_girl));
        memeList.add(new Meme("depressed dog", R.drawable.depressed));
        memeList.add(new Meme("doesn't matter rock", R.drawable.doesntmatter));
        memeList.add(new Meme("doge", R.drawable.doge));
        memeList.add(new Meme("doge alternate", R.drawable.doge2));
        memeList.add(new Meme("drunk baby", R.drawable.drunk_baby2));
        memeList.add(new Meme("drunk obama", R.drawable.drunk_obama));
        memeList.add(new Meme("dumbstruck koala", R.drawable.dumbstruck_koala));
        memeList.add(new Meme("dwight schrute", R.drawable.dwight_schrute));
        memeList.add(new Meme("engineering professor ", R.drawable.engg_prof));
        memeList.add(new Meme("everywhere toy story ", R.drawable.everywhere));
        memeList.add(new Meme("evil raccoon plotting", R.drawable.evil_racc));
        memeList.add(new Meme("evil toddler", R.drawable.evil_toddler));
        memeList.add(new Meme("facepalm picard ", R.drawable.facepalm));
        memeList.add(new Meme("finally over", R.drawable.finally_over));
        memeList.add(new Meme("first day on the internet kid", R.drawable.first_day_on_the_internet_kid));
        memeList.add(new Meme("first world problems", R.drawable.first_world_problems));
        memeList.add(new Meme("futurama fry", R.drawable.futurama_fry));
        memeList.add(new Meme("gay seal", R.drawable.gay_seal));
        memeList.add(new Meme("gollum", R.drawable.gollum));
        memeList.add(new Meme("gordon ramsay", R.drawable.gordon_ramsay));
        memeList.add(new Meme("grumpy cat", R.drawable.grumpy_cat));
        memeList.add(new Meme("grumpy cat 2", R.drawable.grumpy_cat1));
        memeList.add(new Meme("heavy breathing cat", R.drawable.heavy_breathing_cat));
        memeList.add(new Meme("high guy", R.drawable.high_guy));
        memeList.add(new Meme("happy cat", R.drawable.cat_smile));
        memeList.add(new Meme("i'll have you know", R.drawable.ill_have_you_know));
        memeList.add(new Meme("impossibru", R.drawable.impossibru));
        memeList.add(new Meme("if you know what i mean", R.drawable.iykwim));
        memeList.add(new Meme("jackie chan", R.drawable.jackie));
        memeList.add(new Meme("kejriwal happy", R.drawable.kejri));
        memeList.add(new Meme("kejriwal angry", R.drawable.kejru_angry));
        memeList.add(new Meme("kejriwal2", R.drawable.kejri2));
        memeList.add(new Meme("kermit frog(none of my business)", R.drawable.none_business));
        memeList.add(new Meme("kim jong un sad", R.drawable.kim_jong_un_sad));
        memeList.add(new Meme("the joker", R.drawable.joker));
        memeList.add(new Meme("lame pun eel", R.drawable.lame_pun_eel));
        memeList.add(new Meme("laughing obama", R.drawable.laughing_obama));
        memeList.add(new Meme("lazy college senior", R.drawable.lazy_college_senior));
        memeList.add(new Meme("great gatsby leo", R.drawable.leo_cheers));
        memeList.add(new Meme("liam neeson", R.drawable.liam_neeson));
        memeList.add(new Meme("lion king", R.drawable.lk));
        memeList.add(new Meme("look at all these..", R.drawable.look_at_all));
        memeList.add(new Meme("matrix morpheus", R.drawable.matrix_morpheus));
        memeList.add(new Meme("mj popcorn", R.drawable.mj_popcorn));
        memeList.add(new Meme("mr.bean", R.drawable.mr_bean));
        memeList.add(new Meme("naacho bc", R.drawable.naacho_bc));
        memeList.add(new Meme("NaMo checkout", R.drawable.namo_china));
        memeList.add(new Meme("Namo ", R.drawable.namo_s));
        memeList.add(new Meme("nana angry", R.drawable.nana_angry));
        memeList.add(new Meme("naughty baby", R.drawable.baby_naughty));
        memeList.add(new Meme("nobody cares", R.drawable.nobody_cares));
        memeList.add(new Meme("one does not simply..", R.drawable.boromir1));
        memeList.add(new Meme("osama bomb people", R.drawable.boromir1));
        memeList.add(new Meme("not bad obama", R.drawable.not_bad_obama));
        memeList.add(new Meme("pissed obama", R.drawable.obama_pissed));
        memeList.add(new Meme("weird expression obama", R.drawable.obama2));
        memeList.add(new Meme("patrick star", R.drawable.patrick_star));
        memeList.add(new Meme("rare pepe", R.drawable.pepe));
        memeList.add(new Meme("bad luck sad pepe", R.drawable.pepe_sad));
        memeList.add(new Meme("philosoraptor", R.drawable.philosoraptor));
        memeList.add(new Meme("plotting raccoon and human", R.drawable.plotting_racc));
        memeList.add(new Meme("professor oak", R.drawable.prof_oak));
        memeList.add(new Meme("good guy putin", R.drawable.putin_good));
        memeList.add(new Meme("rajanikanth mind it!", R.drawable.rajani_mindit));
        memeList.add(new Meme("raga's babbar sher", R.drawable.rahul_babbarsher));
        memeList.add(new Meme("Rahul gandhi depressed", R.drawable.rahul1));
        memeList.add(new Meme("raga worrying", R.drawable.rahul2));
        memeList.add(new Meme("rich men laughing", R.drawable.rich_men_lol));
        memeList.add(new Meme("sad polar bear", R.drawable.sad_polar));
        memeList.add(new Meme("sarcastic nicholas cage", R.drawable.sarcastic_nicholas_cage));
        memeList.add(new Meme("sansakari alok nath", R.drawable.aloknath1));
        memeList.add(new Meme("scared baby", R.drawable.scared_baby));
        memeList.add(new Meme("scumbag steve", R.drawable.scumbag_steve));
        memeList.add(new Meme("shut up and take my money", R.drawable.shut_up_money));
        memeList.add(new Meme("severus snape", R.drawable.snape));
        memeList.add(new Meme("so much win picard", R.drawable.so_much_win));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spiderman hospital", R.drawable.spiderman_hospital));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spiderman table", R.drawable.spiderman_jerk));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spiderman peter parker", R.drawable.spiderman_peter_parker));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spidey approves", R.drawable.spidey_approves));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spidey butt", R.drawable.spidey_butt));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spidey high", R.drawable.spidey_high));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spidey hot", R.drawable.spidey_hot));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spidey whisper", R.drawable.spidey_whisper));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spongebob and obama", R.drawable.sponge_obaa));
        memeList.add(new Meme("spongebob rainbow", R.drawable.spongebob_nocare));
        memeList.add(new Meme("squidward hard work", R.drawable.squid_hard_work));
        memeList.add(new Meme("squidward realisation", R.drawable.squidward));
        memeList.add(new Meme("sudden realisation", R.drawable.sudden_realisation));
        memeList.add(new Meme("surprised vegeta", R.drawable.surprized_vegeta));
        memeList.add(new Meme("surprised nigga", R.drawable.nigga));
        memeList.add(new Meme("swag cat", R.drawable.cool_cat));
        memeList.add(new Meme("sweet brown", R.drawable.sweet_brown));
        memeList.add(new Meme("that escalaed quickly", R.drawable.that_escalate));
        memeList.add(new Meme("that would be great", R.drawable.that_would_be_great));
        memeList.add(new Meme("the most interesting man", R.drawable.the_most_interesting_man));
        memeList.add(new Meme("third world sceptical kid", R.drawable.third_world_skeptical_kid));
        memeList.add(new Meme("third world dancing kids", R.drawable.third_world_success_kid));
        memeList.add(new Meme("to do list", R.drawable.to_do_list));
        memeList.add(new Meme("tony stark", R.drawable.tony));
        memeList.add(new Meme("too damn high", R.drawable.too_high));
        memeList.add(new Meme("troll cry face", R.drawable.troll_cry));
        memeList.add(new Meme("troll face", R.drawable.troll_face));
        memeList.add(new Meme("troll forever alone", R.drawable.troll_foreverlone));
        memeList.add(new Meme("like a boss", R.drawable.troll_lab));
        memeList.add(new Meme("troll angry no", R.drawable.troll_no));
        memeList.add(new Meme("troll shocked", R.drawable.troll_shock));
        memeList.add(new Meme("trump", R.drawable.trump));
        memeList.add(new Meme("proud trump", R.drawable.proud_trump));
        memeList.add(new Meme("unhelpful high school teacher", R.drawable.unhelpful_high_school_teacher));
        memeList.add(new Meme("Victory baby", R.drawable.celeb_baby));
        memeList.add(new Meme("waiting..", R.drawable.wait));
        memeList.add(new Meme("what?", R.drawable.what2));
        memeList.add(new Meme("troll why?", R.drawable.why));
        memeList.add(new Meme("Balotelli why always me?", R.drawable.why_always_me));
        memeList.add(new Meme("Willy wonka", R.drawable.willy_wonka));
        memeList.add(new Meme("wtf jackie", R.drawable.wtf_jackie));
        memeList.add(new Meme("yo dawg", R.drawable.yo_dawg));
        memeList.add(new Meme("yo goose", R.drawable.yo_goose));
        memeList.add(new Meme("y you no..", R.drawable.yuno));
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private MemeListActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MemeListActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try removing this custom touch listener? maybe it's somehow interfering with scrolling

Comment: i tried that
the lag persists

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting the number of items added at a single instance maybe to 10 or 20 and create an endless scroll. So when the user reaches the bottom, new items will be added to the list.

For creating a endless scroll code:

```
    private boolean loading = true;
    int oldVisibleItems, numberOfVisibleItem, totalNumberOfItem;

        rView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
            {
                if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    numberOfVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalNumberOfItem = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    oldVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading)
                    {
                        if ( (numberOfVisibleItem + oldVisibleItems) >= totalNumberOfItem)
                        {
                            loading = false;
                            Log.d("Check for last item", "This is last item");

                        }

//Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How do I use this exactly?Will I have to create a separate class for it? I'm still an amateur so  would need some help